# Clojure: is there a way to load leiningen plugins as libraries?

Tags: clojure, leiningen

### Question:

Is there a way to load a lein plugin, say codex or lein-beanstalk, as a clojure *library* ?

### Context:

I'm writing some tools for managing my lein projects, and I keep finding myself wanting to have the functionality of lein plugins as libraries in my code -- but I don't see a way to access the lein-pluins namespaces from clojure user land.

### EDIT:

In particular, I want to use: https://github.com/weavejester/codox

I want to be able to do the equiv of "lein doc" but from inside of a "lein repl."

The problem is that I can't load the codox.codox.core namespace.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course you can do it. Leiningen plugins are plain maven artifacts. All you need to do is to specify your plugin in `:dependencies` clause in `project.clj`, like this:

```
   :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.3.0"]
                  [lein-beanstalk "0.2.2"]]
```

Then run `lein deps` and Leiningen will download needed plugin into your lib directory.

Comment: Sorry for my vague (concrete example less question). Can you show me how to run "lein doc" with the codoc lein module, loaded as a library? Thanks!

Comment: @user1311390: have you tried to talk to the devs on IRC? They're all mostly available, and if it's something that doesn't exist in Leiningen, asking there might be more influential in pointing them to your needs for a plugin or hook that they might not have yet: http://webchat.freenode.net  and join channel #leiningen.

Comment: Sorry for my late answer. user1311390, you see, nothing prevents you adding the same artifact to `:dependencies` and to `:modules` clauses (it may not be `:modules`, I don't remember exactly) at the same time. Then you can use `lein` plugin commands as usual.